# DataBinding Android

Tags: android, android-databinding

I'm working on an application and using data binding to inflate data in fragments, when I use the same fragment to inflate different user data and then back press the data doesn't change.

So does data binding library also performs data caching? If so how can we disable that?

Comment: How are you passing the object ?
Did you add a variable in the layout?
Are you passing the variable when you instantiate the binding?
How you handle the backPress?

Answer (score 0):

Trying re-initiating your `ViewModel` on back press, so when you come to your `fragment` for second time, you can populate with new data.

Answer (score 0):

`Databinding` observing on the value that you set and it will not be updated till this value is changed or updated.

Be sure that your updating the data or your `ViewModel` updating after back pressing.